# Search dialog search suggestion

Tags: android

I have implemented search dialog and online search suggestion. But I want when user click on suggestion to copy string from suggestion list to search dialog and when user click on search button to start searching. Now when user click on suggestion searching is automatic start.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html#RewritingQueryText which lists 3 different approaches to do this as per below:

1)  Add the android:searchMode attribute to your searchable configuration with the "queryRewriteFromText" value. In this case, the content from the suggestion's SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1 column is used to rewrite the query text.

2)  Add the android:searchMode attribute to your searchable configuration with the "queryRewriteFromData" value. In this case, the content from the suggestion's SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA column is used to rewrite the query text. This should only be used with URI's or other data formats that are intended to be user-visible, such as HTTP URLs. Internal URI schemes should not be used to rewrite the query in this way.

3)  Provide a unique query text string in the SUGGEST_COLUMN_QUERY column of your suggestions table. If this column is present and contains a value for the current suggestion, it is used to rewrite the query text (and override either of the previous implementations).